# Android VpnService using JSch SSH-Connection: It connects to the server, but it does not have access to the Internet

Tags: java, android, ssh, vpn, jsch

I am using the source below to connect to the server via SSH. There aren't any errors in the program.

The key icon will appear at the top of the mobile screen:

[VPN Connected Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uGew.jpg).

But I do not have access to the Internet:

[No Internet Access Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLUbt.jpg).

I tested with other software, such as napsternetV and NetMod (SSH), and the problem is not with the [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). Why is the Internet not connecting?

#### MainActivity

```
package com.example.myapplication;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.VpnService;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button startVpnButton = findViewById(R.id.start_vpn_button);
            startVpnButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = VpnService.prepare(getApplicationContext());
                if (intent != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else {
                    onActivityResult(0, RESULT_OK, null);
                }
            });
            Button stopVpnButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_vpn_button);
            stopVpnButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyVpnService.class);
                stopService(intent);
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyVpnService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### MyVpnService

```
    package com.example.myapplication;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.VpnService;
    import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
    import android.system.OsConstants;
    import android.util.Log;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
    import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MyVpnService extends VpnService {
        private ParcelFileDescriptor vpnInterface;
        private Session sshSession;

        // Implement onCreate, onStartCommand, and onDestroy methods
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            // Initialize JSch and set up the SSH connection
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            try {
                sshSession = jsch.getSession("SERVER_USERNAME", "SERVER_IP", SERVER_PORT);
            } catch (JSchException e) {

                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            sshSession.setPassword("SERVER_PASSWORD");
            sshSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Thread vpnThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {

                    sshSession.connect();
                    int port_forwarded = sshSession.setPortForwardingL(0, "localhost", 1080);

                    // Configure the VPN connection
                    VpnService.Builder builder = new VpnService.Builder();
                    builder.setSession("MyVpnService")
                            .addAddress("10.0.0.1", 24)
                            .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
                            .addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
                            .setBlocking(true)
                            .establish();

                    vpnInterface = builder.establish();

                    // Add this line to route all traffic through the VPN
                    builder.allowFamily(OsConstants.AF_INET);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            vpnThread.start();
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (vpnInterface != null) {
                try {
                    vpnInterface.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (sshSession != null) {
                sshSession.disconnect();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    }
```

#### AndroidManifest

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
            tools:targetApi="31">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <service
                android:name=".MyVpnService"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.VpnService" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

There aren't any errors in the logs, and the program works perfectly. I even entered the wrong server information, and the program did not connect to the server. It means that the code is working correctly, but I don't know why the Internet is not connecting.

[MainScreen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMMEW.jpg)

Comment: Should a VPNService create an SSH tunnel and just work? I understand a VPN and an SSH tunnel are different things.

Comment: @aled NapsternetV and NetMod are for VPN client. They also have SSH

Comment: You may want to [provide the error message as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

The apps you mentioned use a SOCKS proxy that is created by SSH's dynamic port forwarding. (`ssh -D`)

Currently, your app does not handle any packets intercepted by the VPN interface.

To achieve this you need to be able to forward packets intercepted by the VPN interface to a SOCKS proxy and receive packets from that SOCKS proxy and forward them to the VPN interface.

This task is not easy at all because VPNs and SOCKS proxies are on different layers of the OSI model. But fortunately, there is already an open-source library for this matter called [Tun2Socks](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn) which can connect your VPN interface to a SOCKS proxy.
***You would need JNI to use it since it's written in C.***

Also, the JSch library does not provide support for dynamic port forwarding.
An alternative to the JSch library is the [Apache MINA-sshd](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd) which provides support for a wide range of SSH options including dynamic port forwarding.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)? (Not a rhetorical question.)